# Process.Start and allocated resources

Tags: c#, .net, process, resources

I have this piece of code:

```
Process pLight = new Process();
pLight.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
pLight.StartInfo.FileName = "MyCommand.exe";
//
pLight.StartInfo.Arguments = "-myparam 0";
pLight.Start();
//
pLight.StartInfo.Arguments = "-myparam 1";
pLight.Start();
//
pLight.StartInfo.Arguments = "-myparam 2";
pLight.Start();
```

The question is: a new process is "created" each time i invoke `Start()`?

From `Process.Start` documentation:

> Returns true if a process resource is started; false if no new process resource is started (for example, if an existing process is reused).

but each time i invoke this method i get **true**. So how can I reuse the same process? Is there a way to run multiple commands using the same process?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
pLightStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
pLightStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
pLightStartInfo.FileName = "MyCommand.exe";
pLightStartInfo.Arguments = "-myparam 0";
pLightStart();
pLightStartInfo.Arguments = "-myparam 1";
pLightStart();
pLightStartInfo.Arguments = "-myparam 2";

Process pLight = new Process(pLightStartInfo); // first time so a new Process will be started

Process myOtherProcess = Process.Start(pLightStartInfo); // second time so myOtherProcess would reuse pLight, given original hadn't closed so both would be "pointing" at one MyCommand.exe
```

Never done it myself but that's what it appears to mean.

Comment: Not sure on that one, (equality vs equivalence) Same Process id / handle thingy would be what I'd look for.

Comment: This answer is speculation only and actually doesn't work (even after the necessary corrections). If pLight was 'reused' in some way, then according to the documentation myOtherProcess would be null. It isn't.

Answer (score 0):

If I read this correctly, all you need to do is create a new instance of `ProcessStartInfo` and then if there is a `Process` running, it reuses that.

> Use this overload to start a process resource by specifying a ProcessStartInfo instance. The overload associates the resource with a new Process component. If the process is already running, no additional process resource is started. Instead, the existing process resource is reused and no new Process component is created. In such a case, instead of returning a new Process component, Start returns null to the calling procedure.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w4h05yb.aspx (First line under remarks)